# Switch dataframe float numbers column into dataframe percentages column

Tags: python, pandas

This is my df_neweigenvalue pandas dataframe:

```
    Eigenvalues  Explained proportion
1      19.73283               0.98664
2       0.24447               0.01222
3       0.01922               0.00096
4       0.00277               0.00014
5       0.00063               0.00003
6       0.00008               0.00000
7       0.00001               0.00000
8       0.00000               0.00000
9       0.00000               0.00000
10      0.00000               0.00000
11      0.00000               0.00000
12      0.00000               0.00000
13      0.00000               0.00000
14      0.00000               0.00000
15      0.00000               0.00000
16      0.00000               0.00000
17      0.00000               0.00000
18      0.00000               0.00000
19      0.00000               0.00000
20      0.00000               0.00000
```

I tried to use this code to convert the second column into percentages but it doesn't seem to work:

```
df_neweigenvalue.style.format({'Explained proportion': '{:.2%}'})
```

The error I'm getting is this one:

```
pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x0000027446D79D90>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The pandas styler is for table _visualization_. Are you trying to change the values in the column to formatted string, or are you trying to create a styled table for something like a Juypter notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

Try:

```
df['proportion']=df['proportion'].mul(100).map('{:,.2f}%'.format)
#for whole dataframe use:
#df=df.mul(100).applymap('{:,.2f}%'.format)
```

OR

```
df['proportion']=df['proportion'].mul(100).round(2).astype(str)+'%'
#for whole dataframe use(numeric columns):
#df=df.mul(100).round(2).astype(str)+'%'
```

Comment: If I use your first recommendation I get the percentage sign behind the number, but it doesn't turn the number into percentages between 0 to 100%, i.e. the first entry remains 0.99% instead of 98.66% . What modifications do I need to do to achieve that?

Comment: @Lumberjack88 updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**